# tomcat does not show error message when sendError used from servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Ok so I have a pretty simple webapp using a Servlet and in some cases I send and error back to the client like:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Did not specify parameter xyz");
```

This works fine in general but Tomcat(6.0.33 and Java 1.6.0_26-b03) does not show the given error message from above.

If I run the application on a different container like glassfish the given message is shown.

So, example output ....

```
Tomcat:
400 - Bad Request

Glassfish:
400 - Did not specify parameter xyz
```

Is it possible to configure tomcat to behave in the same way?

Comment: Do you have a custom error page set in your project?

Comment: No; no custom error page. It does still show the custom HTML page that tomcat defaults to, and the message I send is visible in there. Glassfish behaves the same way; but it also uses the message as the basic error message that is returned whereas tomcat still uses 'bad request'.

Comment: I was asking because Tomcat 6.0.X had a bug related to failing to send custom messages with "sendError" when a custom error page was involved.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't specified any in my web.xml and I didn't see any in the default web.xml but I'll double check, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem. Also for further reference check this page...https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42409

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok after some more digging I found the solution here: [How to properly send an HTTP message to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100869/how-to-properly-send-an-http-message-to-the-client)

You need to set:

```
org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER = true
```

in /conf/catalina.properties

This causes tomcat to send the error message you set in the headers 'properly' :)

Answer (score 4):

**Tomcat no longer supports** `USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER` property.

Changelog from [version 8.5.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html):

> RFC 7230 states that clients should ignore reason phrases in HTTP/1.1
>   response messages. Since the reason phrase is optional, Tomcat no
>   longer sends it. As a result the system property
>   org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER is no longer used
>   and has been removed. (markt)

Comment: yep.. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you would like to create a custom error page, like 400.jsp, and place it in the web.xml as

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
.. . path to the page (sorry I don't remember the exact syntax)
</error-page>
```

On this error page you can obtain this message and show it to user.
The benefits of custom error pages is that you can apply your own css styles, your-site-specific markup, etc.

**UPD:**
if you do not like custom err pages:
we used this code in RESTful API for sending back to user response with error and message

```
return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("My message here).build();
```

Comment: A custom error page isn't really the right solution here. The servlet serves a RESTful API so I'm just doing posts to it etc, the user never actually is redirected to an error page. So against tomcat when I get an error back on a POST instead of showing a meaningful message it just gets 'Bad Request' :(

Comment: so what's the problem with redirecting user to the nice error page? it will be done automatically if you specify it in the web.xml, so no any other coding to write

Comment: This is an API not a typical website. APIs don't redirect. Other client-applications make RESTful calls to the API and handle the responses appropriately. With tomcat behaving this way they are not getting the correct error messages returned from the API.

Comment: added the update to answer.. sorry for the first misunderstanding

Comment: No worries, thx for reply :) We aren't using standard ws stuff so that won't work but I found the setting in tomcat anyways, I knew it must be configurable somewhere!