# Override the HTTP response status text

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, httpresponse

How can I override in Tomcat 7 the text of the `HttpStatu`s.

I'm using `HttpServletResponse.sendError(401, "Invalid username or Password")`, but when I'm looking at the response status in the client it goves `401 Unauthorized`.

Is there any way to override it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How to show user-friendly error page..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748220/how-to-show-user-friendly-error-page-instead-of-tomcat-log-with-stack-trace-in-b).

Comment: @dcsohl Not a duplicate. This question is about the HTTP header. The other is about custom error pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `catalina.properties` and add the property:

```
org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true
```

With that set in my dev environment, then when I do:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, 
                   "A very very very bad request");
```

I see:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 A very very very bad request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1024
Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2013 11:09:54 GMT
Connection: close
```

Also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100869/how-to-properly-send-an-http-message-to-the-client) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174285/tomcat-does-not-show-error-message-when-senderror-used-from-servlet)

Comment: This may not be relevant but some clients (e.g. iOS safari will not respect your custom responseText)

Answer (score 6):

**Tomcat no longer supports** `USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER` property.

Changelog from [8.5.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html):

> RFC 7230 states that clients should ignore reason phrases in HTTP/1.1
> response messages. Since the reason phrase is optional, Tomcat no
> longer sends it. As a result the system property
> org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER is no longer used
> and has been removed. (markt)

RFC 7230, *Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing*, June 2014. [Section 3.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2):

> The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing
> a    textual description associated with the numeric status code,
> mostly    out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols
> that were    more frequently used with interactive text clients.  **A
> client SHOULD    ignore the reason-phrase content**.

Answer (score 4):

No - the response codes are set according to RFC 2616. If you want to communicate a message to the user (to the API client) either write it in the body or in a response header

Comment: True, response codes are specified in the RFC but the "Reason Phrase" (which is what the question is about) can be anything you like. (See section [rfc2616 section 6.1.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6.1.1) "The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol."