# how can return json using response.senderror

Tags: spring-mvc

In my app,I use springMVC and tomcat,my controller return object,but when something wrong,I only want return some string message with content tye json,so I use response.error, but it not work,the return is a html.
my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/{name}" ,method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public @ResponseBody UserBean  login(@PathVariable String id,@PathVariable("name") String userName,
        @RequestHeader(value = "User-Agent") String user_agen,
        @CookieValue(required = false) Cookie userId,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody UserBean entity
        ) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("dsdsd");
     System.out.print(userName);

     response.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "somethind wrong");
     return  null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Javadoc for the `HttpServletReponse#sendError` method:

> Sends an error response to the client using the specified status. **The
>   server defaults to creating the response to look like an
>   HTML-formatted server error page containing the specified message,
>   setting the content type to "text/html",** leaving cookies and other
>   headers unmodified...

So `sendError` will generate an HTML error page using the message that you supplied and will override the content type to `text/html`.

Since the client end is expecting a JSON response, you may be better to manually set the response code and the message yourself using fields on your `UserBean` - assuming it can support it. That will then be serialized to a JSON response that your clientside Javascript can evaluate.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/{name}" ,method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody UserBean  login(@PathVariable String id,@PathVariable("name") String userName,
        @RequestHeader(value = "User-Agent") String user_agen,
        @CookieValue(required = false) Cookie userId,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody UserBean entity
        ) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("dsdsd");
     System.out.print(userName);

     response.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
     response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

     UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
     userBean.setError("something wrong"); // For the message
     return userBean;
```

There is also the option of using the Tomcat property `org.apache.coyote. USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER` which will place the message into a custom response header. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100869/how-to-properly-send-an-http-message-to-the-client) and [the Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks,this is a great solution .But the problem is all the response bean must hava a field name error ,it is not so friendly. well,it still a successful resolution.

Comment: Perhaps there is a base class that `UserBean` (and other beans) inherit from that could contain the `error` property? That would save on duplication. Alternatively there's also the possibility of the `USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER` Tomcat specific property that I mentioned in the answer. Then you wouldn't need the `error` property.