# Exception occurs when I try to pass a custom error to client in spring boot application

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, httpresponse

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed**

As above mentioned I am getting an error in the line response .sendError() method. I have searched the internet for 4 days. But I couldn't figure out the problem. What can be the reason for this problem?

I have a custom exception class.
In the following code, the catch block is successfully caught my custom exception. But when I try to send it to the client side it returns the exception mentioned above.

I have already tried
Solution 1 – The Controller level @ExceptionHandler
Solution 2 – The HandlerExceptionResolver
Solution 3 – @ControllerAdvice
Solution 4 – ResponseStatusException

Ways to resolve the above issue. But non-worked for me :(

I have added the error code and the error message to the response body. Then I can get the error successfully. But that is not the way I want.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMemberID/", method=RequestMethod.POST ,headers ="Accept=application/json")
public  ResponseMemberID getMemberID(@RequestBody RequestMemberID request,HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest _request ) throws Exception {

    Member_info memberinfo = new Member_info();
    ResponseMemberID _response =new ResponseMemberID();

    try {
          memberinfo = memberinfoservice.getMemberID(request.getPin(),request.getMsisdn());
          _response.setMember_id(memberinfo.getMember_id()); 

    }catch(MemberNotFoundException exp) {

                 response.sendError(exp.getErrorCode(), exp.getErrorMessage());
    } 

    return _response;
}
```

I need to get the error code and error message as a JSON response using above sendError() method. The exception is successfully coming to the catch block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320074/how-can-return-json-using-response-senderror

Comment: @Ankur This is not a duplicate. Please read my problem carefully and suggest me a solution. Because I have even already tried what you have provided as the duplicate. What I need is to get the error message as spring boot default response. But I am getting an error. That is my problem. Your mentioned solution is working fine. But what I need is to return error by using sendError() method using the HttpResponse

Comment: You are trying to send json response from sendError() method, while the documentation states that sendError() defalts to html text (As mentioned in that answer)

Comment: But one of my colleagues tried the same code and he got the response in JSON format using sendError() method without any conflict. What I am stuck in is I did the same thing but I am not getting back the result in the way I want. I want to know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class MemberController {

@Autowired
MemberInfoService memberinfoservice;


@RequestMapping(value="/getMemberID/", method=RequestMethod.POST ,headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseMemberID getMemberID(@RequestBody RequestMemberID request) throws  Exception{

    Member_info memberinfo = new Member_info();
    ResponseMemberID _response =new ResponseMemberID();

       memberinfo = memberinfoservice.getMemberID(request.getPin(),request.getMsisdn());

       if(memberinfo == null) {

           throw new PINNotValidException();

       }
       _response.setMember_id(memberinfo.getMember_id());

    return _response;

}

@ExceptionHandler(PINNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
    error.setErrorCode(PSAExceptionCodes.PIN_VALIDATION_FAIL);
    error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Above mentioned is the code I've changed according to the link http://www.jcombat.com/spring/exception-handling-in-spring-restful-web-service and it satisfies my problem.

Furthermore, I also tried using **HttpServletResponse** class's **sendError()** method in my application I created but it always returned an empty response.

But by using @ExceptionHandler for custom exception while creating separate *PINNotValidException.class*,*ErrorResponse.class* ,*PSAException.class* and *PSAExceptionCodes.class* I could easily solve my problem.Below mentioned are those classes respectively.

**PINNotValidException.class**

```
public class PINNotValidException extends PSAException{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String errorMessage = "Pin Number and Mobile Number mismatch.";
private static int errorCode = PSAExceptionCodes.PIN_VALIDATION_FAIL;

public PINNotValidException() {
    super(errorMessage, errorCode);
 }
}
```

**ErrorResponse.class**

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private int errorCode;
    private String message;

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**PSAException.class**

```
public class PSAException extends Exception {
private static final long serialVersionUID= 100L;

private String errorMessage;
private int errorCode;

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}
public int getErrorCode(){
    return errorCode;
}
public PSAException(String errorMessage) {
    super(errorMessage);
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}
public PSAException(String errorMessage, int errorCode) {
    super(errorMessage);
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    this.errorCode=errorCode;
}
public PSAException() {
    super();
}
}
```

**PSAExceptionCodes.class**

```
public class PSAExceptionCodes {

public static final int PIN_VALIDATION_FAIL = 251;      //Pin and mobile mismatch 
public static final int ACCOUNT_TYPE_NOT_FOUND = 300;     //Account type mismatch
public static final int NO_MEMBER_FOUND = 250;            //Member Not Found
public static final int MEMBER_NOT_REGISTERED = 256;      //Member not registered

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, 
  1) You need to add error handler for custom exception
  2) And error handler will throw exception

Some useful link: [Recommended way of dealing with spring hibernate SQL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846360/recommended-way-of-dealing-with-spring-hibernate-sql-errors/50850529#50850529)

[Is there a simpler exception handling technique for Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008530/is-there-a-simpler-exception-handling-technique-for-spring/51008726#51008726)

Note: This approach is tested and I'm using it in my application.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
    @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


       @ExceptionHandler(MemberNotFoundException .class)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        public Map<String, String> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
         Map<String, String> response = new HashMap);
        // set your response
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, ex.getStatus());
       }

    }
```

From, `getMemberID`, remove `try` and `catch` block.

Comment: I did try @ExceptionHandler Solution as I mentioned in my question. But did not satisfy what I needed. But really thanks for the links you shared. Went through the links as well.Still no luck.

Comment: Also, I removed the _try catch_ block in _getMemberID_