# How to suppress Spring boot error message

Tags: spring-boot

Team,

The Spring boot throws error response 405(Correct response),but due to security reason the error message should be suppressed with out path message.

```
{
"timestamp": 1554394589310,
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"exception": 
"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
"message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
"path": "/testproject/datasets12/"
}
```

Help me to solve the issue by returning the response without path message.

Comment: You need to have custom error handler.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954374/exception-occurs-when-i-try-to-pass-a-custom-error-to-client-in-spring-boot-appl/53955767#53955767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Shaunak Patel, the way to handle this is a custom error handler. There are plenty of ways to implement one, but a simple implementation getting you the result you want is something like this

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public Map<String, Object> handleConstraintViolationException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("timestamp", Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
        response.put("status", HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value());
        response.put("error", HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.getReasonPhrase());
        response.put("exception", ex.getClass().getName());
        response.put("message", String.format("Request method '%s' not supported", ex.getMethod()));
        return response;
    }
}
```

A `curl` command to illustrate

```
$ curl -v -X POST 'localhost:8080/testproject/datasets12/'
{
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "timestamp": 1554400755087,
  "status": 405
}
```