# network-communication with xhr(or fetch) and spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Now I am studying about spring-boot.

So I create a view, and send a request by ajax in this page.

Below code is on a javascript in jsp.

```
 fetch("/login/login.ajax",{
    data:{
      "test":"a"
    }
  }).then((res)=>{
    return res.json();
  }).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
  })
```

And below code is on a spring-boot controller

```
@RequestMapping("/login/login.ajax")
@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, Object> login(@RequestBody JSONObject request){
    HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if(request != null){
        Object req = request.get("test");

        System.out.println(req.toString());
        if(req.toString().equals("a")){
            resultMap.put("data","cool");
        }
        else{
            resultMap.put("data","hot");
        }
        log.info("ajax-login");
    }
    else{
        resultMap.put("errorCode", "0001");
    }

    return resultMap;
}
```

and Now
I got this error on console in chrome.

> timestamp: "2020-12-09T09:22:27.095+0000", status: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "Required request body is missing: public java.util….login.LoginCtr.login(org.json.simple.JSONObject)", trace: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotR…java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
> ↵", …}
> error: "Bad Request"
> message: "Required request body is missing: public java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> toast.test.login.LoginCtr.login(org.json.simple.JSONObject)"
> path: "/login/login.ajax"
> status: 400
> timestamp: "2020-12-09T09:22:27.095+0000"
> trace: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> toast.test.login.LoginCtr.login(org.json.simple.JSONObject)
> ↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:161)
> ↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
> ↵   at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
> ...

Well I think it's okay that fetch get an error Because It's not suitable.

But this error get detail source about server-side at client-side.

I want to hide all this error especially about message and trace.

How can I do this? Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, I solved this error.

I read this post.
[How to suppress Spring boot error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520835/how-to-suppress-spring-boot-error-message)

Below code is what I've done.

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, Object> handlingError(Exception err){
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("timestamp", Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
    result.put("status",    HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value());
    result.put("error",     HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.getReasonPhrase());
    result.put("exception", err.getClass().getName());
    result.put("message", String.format("Request method '%s' not supported", err.getCause()));
    log.info("errorHandler");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have  not sent body in the fetch request. perhaps you could do this:

```
    var data={"test":"a"};
    fetch{url,{
    body: JSON.stringfy(data)
              }
         }
```

for reference read the fetch documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: At first, thank you for your advice. But really what I want to do is to delete only error messages not error.
I think this error message that java directory can be saw in web-browser can be shown in other cases.